# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework'. How can I fix this error?

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django. I am using Ubuntu, Apache, and virtualenv. I am running Ubuntu on DigitalOcean. I am trying to use Django and React together. So I downloaded djangorestframework. But when I run the server, I encountered this problem.

```
(new_app) sot232@ubuntu:/var/www/html/django_app/commercial$ python3 manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/sot232/new_app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sot232/new_app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/sot232/new_app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[0](_exception[1]).with_traceback(_exception[2])
  File "/home/sot232/new_app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sot232/new_app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/sot232/new_app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/sot232/new_app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/home/sot232/new_app/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework'
```

I included rest_framework properly in the settings.py file.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'commercial',
]
```

I tried these commands.

```
sudo pip3 install djangorestframework
sudo pip install djangorestframework
sudo pip install django-rest-swagger
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
```

I also tried to install djangorestframework after `sudo su`.

(I tried other suggestions too. But I can't remember those.)

In addition, here's what I got on a python shell.

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import rest_framework
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework'
>>>
```

Here is a dist-packages in case you need it.

```
(new_app) sot232@ubuntu:/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages$ ls
Django-2.2.1.dist-info               pytz-2019.1.dist-info
__pycache__                          rest_framework
corsheaders                          sqlparse
django                               sqlparse-0.3.0.dist-info
django_cors_headers-3.0.0.dist-info  virtualenv-16.5.0.dist-info
djangorestframework-3.9.4.dist-info  virtualenv.py
pytz                                 virtualenv_support
```

How can I fix my problem?

Any help will be appreciated. I saw other posts on StackOverFlow that seem to be similar to mine, but nothing seemed to resolve my problem.

(Edit 1)

While the env is activated, I tried to run `pip install djangorestframework`, and I got this error message.

```
(new_app) sot232@ubuntu:~/new_app/bin$ pip install djangorestframework
Collecting djangorestframework
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1b/fe/fcebec2a98fbd1548da1c12ce8d7f634a02a9cce350833fa227a625ec624/djangorestframework-3.9.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: djangorestframework
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/sot232/new_app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/djangorestframework-3.9.4.dist-info'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

(Edit 2)

I run `pip freeze` and `pip3 freeze`. I received this result.

```
sot232@ubuntu:~/new_app/bin$ source activate
(new_app) sot232@ubuntu:~/new_app/bin$ pip freeze
Django==2.2.1
mysqlclient==1.4.2.post1
pytz==2019.1
sqlparse==0.3.0
```

It seems like rest_framework is not installed on my virtualenv. However, `djangorestframework==3.9.4` is installed globally.

Comment: Are you in the correct virtualenv?

Comment: I am fairly sure that I am in the correct virtualenv.

Comment: Did you use `sudo` when you created the virtualenv?  Sounds like you have based on other comments, and if you want to install `rest_framework` then you'll need to either use sudo when you install it, or preferably delete the virtualenv and recreate without using the root user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything I've tried failed. I simply created another virtualenv and reinstalled everything. Now, it is working like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting error even after installing rest_framework. Then finally, this solution worked for me.

1. Open project in PyCharm IDE
2. Create serializers.py
3. Enter this line - from rest_framework import serializers
4. Hover over the squiggly line and PyCharm would suggest you to install rest_framework

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you're trying to run this with a virtual environment called `new_app` activated while Django REST Framework is installed globally.

You have to ways for solving this:

1. Run `pip install djangorestframework` (and any other you want or need) with the `new_app` environment being active. **Note there is no sudo here**
2. Run your development server with no virtual env active.

Of course, number one is the preferred way. Good luck!

Comment: I tried to run 'pip install djangorestframework'. It gives me an error that I don't have a permission. Do I have to change the user permission?

Answer (score 1):

You can run `pip freeze` to confirm what libraries you have installed in your virtualenv.
Sometimes the library was not installed properly and it will be missing in that list.

Answer (score 0):

Copy a `rest_framework` to your project main dir or install it

Comment: I am not sure what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. 
And I had  run python -m pip install --upgrade pip 
for me was works.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me

```
pip3 install djangorestframework
pip install djangorestframework
pip install djangorestframework-jwt
```

Comment: Thanks, I also had this problem after changing virtualenvfolder.  At last, I solved it with your help

Answer (score 0):

I checked `pip freeze` and my `requirements.txt`. Some of my modules are not listing in `pip freeze`. So reinstalled all the requirements.

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

The above method only works if you have a `requirements.txt`, unless you need to install the missing modules explicitly.